# Override javascript_tag type for json-ld in Rails 3.2.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json-ld

Looking at the underlying code for [javascript_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/javascript_tag) it may not be possible, but does anyone know if it's possible to override the `javascript_tag` default type of `type="text/javascript"` in Rails 3.2.2? Or possible without a lot of janky code?

I'm trying to do something like this, but I can look into other options.

```
javascript_tag type: 'application/ld+json' do
    some stuff here
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking deeper at the source code and replicating what it does without the type override seems to solve the problem. So instead of the `javascript_tag` block, to do this:

```
content_tag(:script, javascript_cdata_section(some_stuff_here), :type => 'application/ld+json')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%script{type: "application/ld+json"}
 :plain
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",        
    "headline": "Headline",       
    "@type": "Article",
    "alternativeHeadline": "Alternative Headline}"
  }
```

Instead of using `:javascript` filter, http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#filters, instead I have used the `%script` tag which allows me to define its `type` by using the `attribute method` that defines the type as `application/ld+json`, http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#attribute-methods

The `:plain` filter, it does not parse the filtered text. This is useful for large blocks of text without HTML tags, when you don’t want lines starting with . or - to be parsed, see doc http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#plain-filter

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.